# upload files from sharepoint online to aws s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, office365, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, power-automate

When any file or folder created in a document library in Sharepoint online, then need to upload that file or folder to AWS S3 bucket with the help of Power Automate.

Also, if any attachment upload in the Sharepoint online list, then also that attachment will upload on AWS S3 bucket.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: When any file or folder is created or upload in sharepoint online document library then that folder or file will also added to my AWS S3 bucket so I will get the public URL for that file from AWS S3 bucket. 

I want to do above step with help of Power Automate (Microsoft Flow). When any Item created or modified into Sharepont online Document Library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created below when the file created or modified in the sharepoint with power automate/MS Flow
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply,
Actually, I need to upload or create file on AWS S3 Bucket when any file or folder created on sharepiont online. 

So Is there any AWS API which we integrate with power automate and upload or create file on AWS S3 Bucket.

Comment: The above one i pasted the flow exactly does what you want, but only thing is when the file loaded/updated at sharepoint, it will copy/move the file to AWS S3 bucket.

Comment: @GRVPrasad Is this possible to copy all files from the existing Sharepoint folder to S3 using power automate?

Comment: Yes it will take all files uploaded into share point

Comment: @GRVPrasad how did you configure the s3 bucket location? I do not see it in your images

Comment: This solution appears to move files within Sharepoint and makes no reference to S3.  This does not answer the question.