# can I copy a file from Sharepoint to AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sharepoint

Is it possible to copy a file from Sharepoint to s3? Preferably coding it from the AWS side.

I've searched but not seeing much out there. There's a similar title but this doesn't answer the question:

[upload files from sharepoint online to aws s3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64981277/upload-files-from-sharepoint-online-to-aws-s3-bucket)

Comment: Could provide some context, i.e. what do you mean by "coding it from s3 side"? Technically, you can just download the file from s3 to your PC and then upload it to SharePoint yourself (or use some online service to do a similar thing for you), but this is probably not what you are after, or?

Comment: Yes, I could download from SP and upload to s3 manually. I was wondering if it's possible to automate the process. I'm familiar with the AWS SDK but know nothing about the backend of Sharepoint.

Comment: I just found that Sharepoint has a REST API, so potentially I could run a script from EC2 or Lambda, connect and download SP file, and save to s3? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints

Comment: Yes, you could.

Comment: you can refer this link : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/create-a-serverless-event-driven-workflow-to-ingest-and-process-microsoft-data-with-aws-glue-and-amazon-eventbridge/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for sure. SharePoint online has a rest API I use a python package called office365, it implements a SharePoint client to handle most of the daily operations you will need.

The repo is: https://github.com/O365/python-o365

Some tips about I have struggled for the first time:

- The ClientContext object requires the base site URL for the SharePoint library you want to authenticate, library doc:
  https://mysharepoint.mydomain.com/sites/mysite/shareddocuments/
- The URL you must pass to the Client context will be: https://mysharepoint.mydomain.com/sites/mysite
- The method UserCredential requires your user in the following format: `user@mydomain`